# How to compare a value with the number of matches for a second query?

Tags: splunk

```
"daily unique entry text" 
| spath input=stats 
| where ('expectedCount' != _???_)
```

I have one daily unique log entry that states the `expectedCount` of items that will be processed for that day.

Let's say this daily entry contains the unique text `daily unique entry text`, and each time an item gets processed successfully, I log `item processed`.

I'd like an alert that fires if `expectedCount` is not equal to the number of `item processed` log entries that follow, in that day.

Can this be accomplished with something at `_???_`? Or: what's the best way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
index=* "item processed" | stats count | append [ search index=* "daily unique entry text" | spath input=stats | fields expectedCount ] | stats values(count) as c, values(expectedCount) as ec | where c != ec
```

I think this is the most straightforward approach, but there are other ways. First search just gets a count of all the items processed. You may need to restrict it to a day of required. Then we append another search, which is just the value of the expected count. We use another stats command to get the value of the actual count and the expected count together. Then, just compare them

Comment: I think there should be a `search` inside `append`'s opening `[`  ... but yup I'm able to get what I need from this -- thanks!

Comment: Yep, you're right about the `search` inside the append, i will update. Glad it helps